# MPI4PY - routed:binomial: Connection to lifeline lost

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I've encountered a very strange error when I was trying to execute a simple Shell-script from a python script. The script is to be executed only by the first node (rank=0). Simple example:

```
import os
from mpi4py import MPI

comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
size=comm.Get_size()
rank=comm.Get_rank()

if rank==0:
        os.system('./simple_script.sh')
else:
        print rank
```

Result:

```
[ws:29907] [[57451,1],0] routed:binomial: Connection to lifeline [[57451,0],0] lost
```

Whats the Problem? Any ideas?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how MPI4PY works, but if it's anything like regular MPI, you have to call `MPI_Init` before you can start doing anything (such as `get_size` or `get_rank`). Try doing that first.

Comment: thx for your answer. In Python MPI_Init() is not necessary...I've found a small Workaround though...